# How to copy part of a string from a specific cell to another cell with Excel macros?

Tags: excel, vba

How do I copy part of a string in a cell to another cell?

For example: In cell A1 it says `Force: 2035N`. I want to copy only the `2035N` part from it from A1 to B1. How do I do that?

I started looking a MID substring. So something like:

```
a=Mid(ActiveSheet.Range(“A1”), 1 5)).
```

But I'm completely new to VBA so I don't really know how to make it work.

Edit: More info.

What I want to copy
[image: What I want to copy]

End result
[image: End result]

I have a CSV file with lots of data in different rows. I want to use a macro so I can sort all this data in a desired order and transpose it so I can just copy it to another excel file.

The characters from the whole string I want to copy from the original cell (let's say they are in cell A1-A7) are in **bold** (in the picture). And this csv file is always in the same order and the characters are in the same place.

I want to copy the **bold** part of the cell from A1-A7 to for example B1-H1.

Comment: Can you explain the logic to identify what needs to be copied? Is it the last 5 characters of the string, or anything after the first space, or can the desired text be elsewhere in the string?  Also, when you start using the MID() function in VBA, do you NOT see the syntax helper that shows you that you need to place commas between parameters??

Comment: Thank you for your comment. The desired characters can be anywhere in the string. I know you can use Left and Right function as well. But I don't really know how to write the code so that it takes the specified characters from the specific cell and the copy it to the desired cell. I did not see that helper unfortunately.

Comment: You can do it by formula only.

Comment: If this is true *"The desired characters can be anywhere in the string."* then this cannot be solved by a computer. You need some kind of pattern do determine how to find the desired characters. This rule how to find them is what you need to explain.

Comment: The way I need to pick the characters is always following the same pattern. For example, in A1 it says "xxxx1234xxxx" then I need to pick "1234". In cell A2 it says "1234xxxx", then I need to pick "1234". In A3 it says, "xxxx1234", then I want 1234. My thinking was that I use the function "left", "right", and "mid" when I need to and hand pick it for each cell. Is this possible?

Comment: @William And how do you know that it is `1234` that you want to pick if it cannot be determined by it's position? That is what needs to be answered! Otherwise you cannot do it.

Comment: Sorry if I confused you. The position is always known. So in the case for 1234xxxx, it's always the first 4, when it's xxxx1234xxxx, it's always 5-8 and so on.

Comment: And where do you have the information which case it is? How do you decide if it is this case`1234xxxx` or this `xxxx1234xxxx` case? By looking at it? Does not work, your logic has a circle. Please [edit] your quesition and provide some real example data (more than one example!) including the result you expect for each data.

Comment: Thanks, appreciate it! I have now updated the OP with 2 pictures are some more info.

Comment: Well If you would import your CSV file correctly (with komma as delimiter) it would be much easier, because then your description (like `Sample ID:`) would be in column A and your values (like `37 A1`) would always be in column B. So you would not need to extract anything but you could just use the data in column B. • Research how to import your CSV properly into Excel and this solves your issue! If all data ends up in column A your CSV was not imported correctly.

Comment: Yes that would be much easier. Unfortunately It's a auto-exported csv file and it's not possible to modify the export unfortunately, which is ashame. Is it possible to use left, right, mid and solve my issue even though the csv file is like this?

Comment: @William It is not a problem of **export**. The issue is how you open / **import** the file in Excel. This is done wrong. This is what you need to fix. The export is fine.

Comment: Or you use the [text to columns feature](https://www.excel-easy.com/examples/text-to-columns.html) in Excel with komma as delimiter.

Comment: Thank you! 
I actually think that will solve it with my existing code. I just separated each word in the string to it's own column. Thank you very much for the help.

Answer (score 1):

Try below sub.

```
Sub SplitString()
    Dim str
    
    str = Split(Range("A1"), " ")
    
    Range("B1") = str(UBound(str))
    
End Sub
```

If you want to use formula only then try-

```
=TRIM(MID(A1,SEARCH(" ",A1)+1,LEN(A1)))
```

[image]

Comment: Thank you for your time. It does work for this instance, but is it possible to modify it if I need for example "Force" in Force: 2035N, or if I need only "20" etc?

Comment: So that I could basically modify the code to pick characters in the beginning, the middle and the end. My thought was that I'll use one line of code for each different scenario. So if I need the first 4 characters, I use one line of code, and if I need the middle characters, I'll use another line of code and so on.